# Is there a LogUnsubEvent/Log an UnsubEvent equivalent for MobileConnect?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobile, mobileconnect, unsubscribe

I'm looking for a MobileConnect version of [LogUnsubEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/unsubEvent.htm) where you can unsubscribe a contact at the All Subscriber level -- or in MobileConnect terms: All Contacts.

My current options I see are:

- Either using [QueueMO API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using-the-mobileconnect-api.htm) and [replicate an inbound SMS message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postQueueMO.htm) to unsubscribe.
- Or [UpsertDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertde.htm) to a data extension and data extract, file transfer, import into All Contacts.

Is there any other way via AMPscript and UnsubEvent to update MobileConnect subscriber status at the All Contact level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the closest solution would be a combination of the [HTTPPost](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httppost.htm) AMPscript function and the [QueueMO API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using-the-mobileconnect-api.htm). Do a lookup on `_MobileAddress` and `_MobileSubscription` in conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

you can evaluate using the contact routes but I would suggest the queuemo and having an empty response so nothing is sent if that is desired.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updateContacts.htm